# Why is $g(v,v)$ the speed in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, speed, metric-space

if $v_{\gamma,p}$ is the velocity along a curve at point $p$ on the manifold of space time, and $g$ is the metric tensor, then $g(v_{\gamma,p},v_{\gamma,p})^{1/2}$, calculated in tensor notation by $(g_{ij}v^iv^j)^{1/2}$ gives the speed.

I don't understand why the speed isn't given by $g(v_{\gamma,p},\vec 0)$ instead. For example, in the Euclidean metric in 2D, $g(v,w)=\sqrt{(v_1-w_1)^2+(v_2-w_2)^2}$, and then if $v=w$, $g$ simply evaluates to $0.$

**Shouldn't the speed along a curve at a point be given by the distance between the velocity tangent vector and the "standing-still" velocity vector, rather than the distance between of the velocity and itself?**

Comment: That quantity doesn't seem very coordinate invariant

Comment: This question (v3) is possibly (partly?) spurred by a conflation of (i) a [metric tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)) $g(X,X)=||X||^2$ in a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold), and  (ii) a [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) $d(x,y)$ in a [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).

Comment: @Qmechanic, I am definitely conflating the two, because I assumed that a metric tensor field is simply a metric on the tangent space (as a metric space) on each point on the manifold. How is this incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

That is not the Euclidean metric. The Euclidean metric in 2 dimensions would look like $g(v,w) = v_1w_1 + v_2w_2$, and the speed would similarly be given by $g(v,v)^{1/2}$.

We define the length of a (timelike) parametrized path $\gamma: [a,b] \to M$, where M is our spacetime, as
$$
L(\gamma) = \int_\gamma d\tau \sqrt{|g_{ij}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j|},
$$
where the overdot notation indicates differentiation with respect to the path parameter (this length is independent of parametrization). Then the "distance" between two points $x$ and $y$ with timelike separation is defined as 
$$
d(x,y) = \mathrm{Sup}\{L(\gamma): \text{ $\gamma$ is a path connecting $x$ and $y$}\}.
$$
Since geodesics maximize the length locally this equates to integration along some geodesic.

In the Euclidean case the distance is instead defined as $\mathrm{Inf}\{L(\gamma)\}$ (this is because of the signature difference), which picks out the straight line, and integration yields the usual distance formula.

As a final note, one does often use the term "metric" to refer to the distance function, while the metric tensor induces an inner product. So the confusion is understandable.

Comment: Are you sure? Wikipedia says the following: "In mathematics, the **Euclidean distance or Euclidean metric** is the "ordinary" (i.e. straight-line) distance between two points in Euclidean space."

Comment: But ok, given that I'm probably misreading wikipedia, would this mean that the Euclidean metric tensor is simply given by $g_{ij}=\delta^i_j$?

Comment: @Programmer2134 In this respect the metric of interest is still a tensor acting on vectors. The distance function they are referring to measures the distance between two points (and thus has nothing to with velocities or speeds, in principle). The two are related by integration along a geodesic (straight line in the Euclidean case) connecting the two points, however. And yes, the Euclidean metric is simply $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Could you explain this: "the two are related by integration along a geodesic"? (I know what a geodesic is). How does this relate them?

Answer (score 0):

> The motion of a material particle, under the action only of inertia and gravitation, is described by the equation

$$ \frac{d^2x_{\mu}}{ds^2} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx_{\alpha}}{ds} \frac{dx_{\beta}}{ds} = 0$$

Which comes from the fact that the parallel displacement of a vector along a curve is given by :

$$ \Delta A^\mu = \oint \delta A^\mu $$
$$  \Delta A^\mu = - \oint \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha \beta}A^\alpha dx_\beta $$

If $A^\mu$ is a 4-vector velocity then this is how you compute it's displacement from a point $P_1$ on the curve to point $P_2$.